# BigQuery: Group by table name

Tags: google-bigquery

My dataset (ds1) looks like the following:

```
2014_01_01_tableA
2014_01_01_tableB

2014_01_02_tableA
2014_01_02_tableB
```

The query:

```
SELECT date, COUNT(1) AS counter 
FROM [ds1.2014_01_01_tableA], [ds1.2014_01_01_tableB], [ds1.2014_01_02_tableA], [ds1.2014_01_02_tableB] 
GROUP BY date;
```

Returns:

```
date, counter
2014-01-01, 100
2014-01-02, 200
```

**Is it somehow possible to group by the table name as well?** Something like this maybe? ...

```
SELECT date, COUNT(1) AS counter, TABLE_NAME() AS table_name
FROM [ds1.2014_01_01_tableA], [ds1.2014_01_01_tableB], [ds1.2014_01_02_tableA], [ds1.2014_01_02_tableB] 
GROUP BY table_name, date;
```

Expected result:

```
date, counter, table_name
2014-01-01, 50, 2014_01_01_tableA
2014-01-01, 50, 2014_01_01_tableB
2014-01-02, 100, 2014_01_02_tableA
2014-01-02, 100, 2014_01_02_tableB
```

`TABLE_NAME() AS table_name` does not exist, unfortunately.

Answer (score 8):

Unfortunately, there isn't a way to do this cleanly. I've added an internal feature request.

The ugly way to do it is:

```
SELECT date, COUNT(1) AS counter, table_name
FROM 
 (SELECT *, "2014_01_01_tableA" as table_name FROM [ds1.2014_01_01_tableA]), 
 (SELECT *, "2014_01_01_tableB" as table_name FROM [ds1.2014_01_01_tableB]), 
 (SELECT *, "2014_01_02_tableA" as table_name FROM [ds1.2014_01_02_tableA]), 
 (SELECT *, "2014_01_02_tableB" as table_name FROM [ds1.2014_01_02_tableB])
GROUP BY table_name, date;
```

Comment: Now that there are "Table wildcard functions" being able to group by the table name feels like it's more needed than ever.

Comment: @jordan-tigani - Has any progress been made on this?

Comment: @jordan-tigani curious about this as well.

Answer (score 5):

This is now possible using `_TABLE_SUFFIX` parameter and table wildcards.

```
SELECT date, COUNT(1) AS counter, _TABLE_SUFFIX as table_name
FROM `ds1.*`
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX IN ('2014_01_01_tableA', '2014_01_01_tableB', '2014_01_02_tableA', '2014_01_02_tableB')
GROUP BY table_name, date
```

`_TABLE_SUFFIX` is whatever is captured by the wildcard in the `FROM` statement.  It can be a partial table suffix or complete table name.  For example, if you use `FROM ds1.2014_01_*` the corresponding _TABLE_SUFFIX would be `01_tableA`.